# Why didn't Hashem warn Adam and Chava about the curses?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sin, adam, eve-chava

Simple question, why did He surprise them with curses? Initially He just said they will surely die if they are the fruit. After they do, He then tells them that not only will they die but lots of other things too.

What justifies this course of action Hashem took, in not initially explaining the comprehensive consequences of the sin?

Comment: Maybe initially He’d hoped that reward and punishment wouldn’t be a determining factor in whether man chooses between right or wrong, but rather was hoping Adam wouldn’t eat from the tree simply out of fear and love and respect for his Creator

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii They knew all along what was going to happen. They wanted to break the bond with G_D and retie it through teshuvah. A bond retied through teshuvah is stronger - My Source: Chabad Chassidus.

Comment: @MarsSojourner I love that idea, heard it from Rabbi Manis Friedman (do you know his source?) I such a case, the point was that these curses are not punishments at all, they are the realization of going to the "lowest world". I would still imagine the question stands to some degree, surely there should have been more explanation of what the lowest world is like? Maybe if I can find that source, it will answer that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the curses for Adam and Eve are not actual curses. They are not some new invented punishment by God for Adam and Eve. Rather they are a description of their new reality. The reality they will be in until they die from it or die because of it.

Eve - She apparently gains the ability to have children from eating from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil. As a result, God explained how childbirth would be for her. And we all know from the future stories in the Bible that childbirth is a very common way for women to die.

Adam - Adam (and his partner) will now be kicked out of the garden. The garden grew food on its own and required no farming. Adam needed to maintain and protect the garden, that's all. Now that he's kicked out he will have to farm the land, and God describes it to him. Even after the curses are done being read, scripture simply states that God sent Adam out from the garden to till the land.

Snake - The snake is the only one that is cursed directly. "Cursed are you..." as opposed to Eve where the word cursed is not at all used, and Adam is also not cursed, but rather the ground is apparently cursed for his sake. But I take that to mean that he will not be in the holy garden, rather he will be in the regular earth which is cursed and scarce and hard to survive in. The snake is an interesting case because animals only have two commandments: eat vegetarian, and have children. We don't see the snake violating either of those commandments, and yet God is holding the snake accountable because God apparently believes that the serpent "should have known better," and because of that, the serpent is the only one who is actually cursed.

Comment: ThrnRan says akmost the reverse. Derashos haRan #1. He says they were forewarned of becoming mortal, because that was a consequence inherent in what they did. Whereas the rest of it were imposed punishments. Perhaps one can suggest a 3-way division: consequence, regular punishment, and curse. But that would be going beyond the Ran.

Answer (score 1):

The Ohr Chaim in Parshas Bresheis chapter 3, which is a very long piece, has an explanation for what each one was punished for. I cannot do justice within this post, please look inside at the or Hachaim. The main part which I love about this or Hachim is they were punished for not taking responsibility for their actions.

•   Adam was commanded to tell his wife not to eat from the Etz Hadass. Adam tells his wife not to touch the tree. This was a Geder he decided was necessary
•   Nachash gets involved and tells her that Adam was lying and nothing will happen. She touches the tree nothing happens.
•   She eats from the tree and gives Adam to eat from the tree. Adam does not question the food his wife gives him and eats as well.
•   They realize they did something wrong.

Then Hashem tells them you did something wrong you ate from the Eitz Hadass.

•   Adam says I am an oness (innocent) do I have to check all the food my wife gives me to make sure it is kosher? Not even a shogeg as you created an ezer knegdo to help me.
•   Chava says the tree looked to beautiful I could not resist to touch it, which I was told was assur. Adam added an issur which was too difficult so I am innocent.
•   Hashem gives Adam a chance for teshuva since at he did eat even if he was innocent. Adam says no.

They then are punished for things they did wrong within their story. What did they do wrong?

•   Adam, yes you are to trust your wife, but you can still ask questions. Triple check to make sure it is kosher. His punishment, he will have to toil on a cursed land in order to provide the raw kosher ingredients. The punishments were for changing the law that caused his wife to sin and not taking responsibility for the cause of changing the law and for not checking if the food was Kosher.
•   Chava, Since your downfall was that you enjoyed the outside look of the tree and could not resist, during the time of the greatest happiness (childbirth) you will be in pain. And for the sin of just enjoying the look, men will lust after your external body instead of an emotional internal connection which you crave.
According to the Or Hachim, in truth although the tree was eaten from it was not a punishable act, rather they were punished for the details of the way they sinned. As such they were not killed on the day they ate.

Comment: A very interesting idea, thank you for all this. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Although now that I think about it, it forces me to prove in my question that we should expect Hashem to warn before cursing. Because this actually didn't answer that, it just answers why Hashem changed it from just death. I'll see if I can back up that assertion at some point. The fact that we've had thousands of years of hard work and pain in childbirth etc, for 2 people doing certain sins (arguably fairly minor) for the first time, without being warned or even told in advance that those things are wrong warrants this question I think.

Comment: I think it has to do with this addition of Adam not to touch the tree, despite being seen as a fence as there are several fences in Judaism, at that specific moment this was negative since the serpent convinced Eve to touch it and nothing happened, that triggered everything, raised doubts about God's order and both Eve and Adam were punished for giving the serpent an opening to exploit. Of course, textually it says none of that but from what they comment we can infer that it might be that.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I highly recommend to learn through the full text of the or Hachaim. While I agree with the question, why are we still being punished for the sin of Adam and Eve, the point I am trying to make is the attuite that Adam and Chava had that they were beyond reproach and punishment is was the cause of the punishment. Mashma, had they said חטאתי, no punishment would have been given according to the or hachaim.

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy the first time my 2 year old does something naughty, something he didn't know was naughty, I don't punish him, but I tell him then and there what the punishment will be for the next time. That's my point. But yes, I'll learn it bli neder

Answer (score 1):

The gra explains that Hashem told Adam what the tree will do to him. The fact Adam became mortal was a result of the tree itself. Then Hashem punished him with the curses for not listening to him.

The Sforno explains that the curses came not for eating from the tree itself, but that he listened to his wife over God caused him to get these curses.

Radak explains that really Adam should've died, but Hashem spared him and gave him the curses instead.